# Starter guide for Apache ServiceMix

Tags: java, documentation, apache-servicemix

What is the definitive guide to start with Apache ServiceMix? The howto's and guides on the website are way too complicate for a clean start.

Answer (score 10):

I am still learning Apache ServiceMix myself. ESB's in generally are pretty complicated. The best book I found is "[Open-Source ESBs in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988215)" published by Manning. It runs MVN/ANT to setup your environment and walks you through with some pretty basic examples. Let me know how you like it.

Comment: Tkx for the fast answer, I'll definitely have a look at the book!

Comment: Hey if the book helped will you mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 8):

here are a few quick notes on getting a development environment going and an intro to Servicemix4 here...

http://benoday.blogspot.com/2010/08/fuse-esb-42-and-osgi-quick-start-guide.html

http://benoday.blogspot.com/2010/08/servicemix-developer-machine-setup.html

Answer (score 4):

I like the six page ref card at DZone which can be found [here](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-servicemix-40).  There's a lot of information packed on it.

You can read it online, or have a download link emailed to you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Update for the version 4.2 [here](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/servicemix)